# WPF length unit is not 1/96 in

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to draw a rectangle with size of 10x10cm using WPF (Canvas). I tried many ways to convert centimeters to pixels. I used the LengthConverter class, I used an explicit assignment (Width="10cm") but the actual width and height of rectangle are less than 10cm (about 9.35cm). It is a bit strange.
As I know, 1 WPF unit == 1/96 inch by default. Where could be a problem?

Here is a piece of my XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}" Background="White" 
                  ClipToBounds="True">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Width="10cm" Height="10cm" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Black"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: It depends on your system DPI setting.

Comment: I tried to get DPI of my display first, but it is always 96.

Comment: If you mean on the screen, that depends on the information Windows will get from the screen what the physical pixel density of the screen is. If that is not absolutely correct it will be off if you go with a real world ruler to the screen. There is not a whole lot you could do. On a print out on the other hand it should be correct. Please specify.

Comment: how can you tell it's approximately 9.35cm how did you measure it ?

Comment: yes, I measured it with a ruler and I need 10cm.

Comment: Well on screen then you are SOL unless you have a screen that will produce the EXACT dimension matching what it reports to windows. You could compensate for a specific screen, but that would not be transferable...